# Querydsl - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No sources given

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I'm building a system using Spring MVC, Thymeleaf, JPA (Hibernate), and Querydsl. While I was testing everything, I came across this exception:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Serviço nulo: false
[SER_USU] - Fazendo consulta...
[SER_USU] - Dao nulo: false

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No sources given
    at com.querydsl.jpa.JPAQueryBase.serialize(JPAQueryBase.java:56)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.JPAQueryBase.serialize(JPAQueryBase.java:50)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.createQuery(AbstractJPAQuery.java:98)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.createQuery(AbstractJPAQuery.java:94)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.fetch(AbstractJPAQuery.java:201)
    at com.regra7.st.db.dao.Dao_Usuario.getPorID(Dao_Usuario.java:35)
    at com.regra7.st.servico.Ser_Usuario.cadastrar(Ser_Usuario.java:46)
    at com.regra7.st.testes.TesteDAO_001.<init>(TesteDAO_001.java:43)
    at com.regra7.st.testes.TesteDAO_001.main(TesteDAO_001.java:19)
```

Unfortunately, this is not very descriptive, and so, I do not know what to do. I've tried everything, but I do not find the solution. And yes, thats all the message (the stacktrace). Here are some files I'm using...

**pom.xml** (I may have some dependencies wrong, I don't know exactly):

```
<project 
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.regra7</groupId>
    <artifactId>Sistema_Teste_001</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- QUERYDSL -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SPRING MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SPRING CONTEXT (SPRING CORE - TRANSIENT) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- POSTGRESQL DRIVER JDBC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- API SERVLET E JSP -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- BEAN VALIDATION -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- IMPLEMENTAÇÃO BEAN VALIDATION (HIBERNATE) -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- THYMELEAF -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- THYMELEAF PARA O SPRING 4 -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.querydsl/querydsl-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.querydsl/querydsl-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.querydsl/querydsl-apt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- C3P0 -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mchange/c3p0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**spring-config.xml (app-context.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<!-- ARQUIVO DE CONFIGURAÇÃO DE CONTEXTO DE APLICAÇÃO. -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd ">

    <!-- Mapeamento de recursos (arquivos css, fontes, imagens, dentre outros). -->
    <!-- <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/WEB-INF/recursos/css/" /> -->
    <!-- <mvc:resources mapping="/imagens/**" location="/WEB-INF/recursos/imagens/" /> -->
    <!-- <mvc:resources mapping="/fontes/**" location="/WEB-INF/recursos/fontes/" /> -->
    <!-- <mvc:resources mapping="/fontes/**" location="/WEB-INF/recursos/javascript/" /> -->

    <!-- Possibilita o uso de anotações Spring Mvc. -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Alternativa a declarar PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor, 
    um processador de anotações que lê @PersistenceContext. -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Define local para procura de componentes Spring (beans configurados 
        por anotações em classes). -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.regra7.st.controle" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.regra7.st.db.dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.regra7.st.servico" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.regra7.st.testes" />

    <!-- MINHA DEFINIÇÃO COM MEUS CONVERSORES CRIADOS -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="servicoConversao"/>

    <!-- PROPERTY EDITOR NÃO FUNCIONOU, MAS ISSO SIM! -->
    <bean id="servicoConversao" 
        class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
        <property name="converters">
            <set>
                <bean class="com.regra7.st.formularios.conversores.Cov_String_LocalDate"/>
                <bean class="com.regra7.st.formularios.conversores.Cov_LocalDate_String"/>
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Template Resolver para Template Engine. -->
    <!-- <bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver"> 
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" /> <property name="suffix" 
        value=".html" /> <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" /> </bean> -->

    <!-- SpringResourceTemplateResolver automatically integrates with Spring's 
        own -->
    <!-- resource resolution infrastructure, which is highly recommended. -->
    <bean id="templateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        <!-- HTML is the default value, added here for the sake of clarity. -->
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML" />
        <!-- Template cache is true by default. Set to false if you want -->
        <!-- templates to be automatically updated when modified. -->
        <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <!-- SpringTemplateEngine automatically applies SpringStandardDialect and -->
    <!-- enables Spring's own MessageSource message resolution mechanisms. -->
    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
        <!-- Enabling the SpringEL compiler with Spring 4.2.4 or newer can speed 
            up -->
        <!-- execution in most scenarios, but might be incompatible with specific -->
        <!-- cases when expressions in one template are reused across different 
            data -->
        <!-- ypes, so this flag is "false" by default for safer backwards -->
        <!-- compatibility. -->
        <property name="enableSpringELCompiler" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <!-- View resolver do Thymeleaf. -->
    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    </bean>

    <!-- DATA SOURCE - Implementação do C3p0 -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <!-- Propriedades de conexão -->
        <property name = "driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name = "jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/SistemaTeste" />
        <property name = "user" value="postgres" />
        <property name = "password" value="admin" />

        <!-- Propriedades C3p0 -->
        <property name = "initialPoolSize"  value="3" />
        <property name = "minPoolSize"      value="5" />
        <property name = "maxPoolSize"      value="20" />
        <property name = "maxIdleTime"      value="1800" /> <!-- 1800 = 30 min -->
        <property name = "maxStatements"    value="50" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Fábrica EntityManager -->
    <bean id="emf"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="SistemaTeste" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaDialect">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">regrast</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Gerenciador de transações PlatformTransactionManager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
    </bean>

    <!-- INTERCEPTADORES -->
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/usuario/*" />
            <bean class="com.regra7.st.interceptadores.Login" />
        </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>

</beans>
```

**persistence.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="SistemaTeste" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <!-- PROVEDOR JPA -->
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

My main **test class**:

```
public class TesteDAO_001 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new TesteDAO_001(); // Line 19
    }

    public TesteDAO_001()
    {
        AbstractApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/META-INF/spring-config.xml");
        Ser_Usuario servico = ac.getBean(Ser_Usuario.class); // Service class

        // For_Cadastro is an account registration form.
        For_Cadastro form = new For_Cadastro();
        form.setNome("Maria Pereira Maxwell"); // Name
        form.setLogin("rodrigologinsoares001");
        form.setSenha1("minhasenha001001"); // Password
        form.setSenha2("minhasenha001001"); // Password confirmation
        form.setCpf("01234567890"); // CPF = Brazil's Social ID
        form.setNascimento(LocalDate.now()); // Birthday
        form.setPai(0L); // Father
        form.setMae(0L); // Mother
        form.setGenero(0L); // Gender

        System.out.printf("Serviço nulo: %s%n" , servico == null);
        servico.cadastrar(form); // Line 43

        ac.close();
    }
}
```

**Service method**:

```
@Autowired
private Dao_Usuario _daoUsu;

@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void cadastrar(For_Cadastro form)
{
    imprimir("Fazendo consulta...");
    imprimir(String.format("Dao nulo: %s%n", this._daoUsu == null));

    // This may return null.    
    Usuario pai = this._daoUsu.getPorID(form.getPai()); // Line 46
    Usuario mae = this._daoUsu.getPorID(form.getMae());

    imprimir(String.format("pai nulo: %s%n", pai == null));
    imprimir(String.format("mea nulo: %s%n", mae == null));

    // Usuario is a Domain Model Object. A POJO representation of a table.
    Usuario usu = new Usuario(form.getCpf()); // CPF = Brazil's Social ID
    usu.setGenero(Genero.getGenero(form.getGenero())); // Gender
    usu.setNome(form.getNome()); // Name
    usu.setLogin(form.getLogin());
    usu.setSenha(form.getSenha1().getBytes()); // Password
    usu.setNascimento(form.getNascimento()); // Birthday
    usu.setMae(mae); // Mother
    usu.setPai(pai); // Father

    imprimir("Modelo criado. Salvando...");
    this._daoUsu.salvarAtualizar(usu); // Save/Update
    imprimir("Persistência concluída.");
}
```

**DAO method:**

```
@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager _em;

@Override
public Usuario getPorID(Long id) 
{   
    if(id == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return new JPAQueryFactory(this._em)
            .select(QUsuario.usuario)
            .where(QUsuario.usuario.id.eq(id))
            .fetchOne(); // Line 32
}
```

I'm learning how to use Querydsl. If you need me to add any more code here, please say so. I already researched google, and also here in the community. Unfortunately I did not find anything about it. Can somebody help me, please?

Thank you for your time and patience.

### EDIT

Here's my **Domain Model Usuario** Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tb_usuarios")
public class Usuario
{
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name="ger_id_usuario" , 
            sequenceName="tb_usuarios_id_seq" , 
            allocationSize=1 , 
            initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE , 
            generator="ger_id_usuario")
    @Column(
            name = "usu_id" , 
            unique = true)
    protected Long id;

    // Name
    @Column(name = "usu_nome" , unique = true)
    protected String nome;

    // "Business Key"
    @Column(name = "usu_login" , unique = true)
    protected String login;

    // Password
    @Column(name = "usu_senha" , unique = true)
    protected byte[] senha;

    // Brazil's Social ID
    // "Business Key"
    @Column(name = "usu_cpf" , unique = true)
    protected String cpf;

    // Registration moment (date and time)
    @Column(name = "usu_nascimento")
    protected Date nascimento;

    // Gender
    @Column(name = "usu_genero")
    protected byte genero;

    // Father of this person (it may be null).
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY , cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "usu_pai")
    protected Usuario pai;

    // Mother of this person (it may be null).
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY , cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "usu_mae")
    protected Usuario mae;

    @Column(name = "usu_cadastro")
    protected Timestamp cadastro;

    // Children as a father.
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="pai" , fetch = FetchType.LAZY , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    protected Set<Usuario> filhosComoPai;

    // Children as a mother.
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="mae" , fetch = FetchType.LAZY , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    protected Set<Usuario> filhosComoMae;

    // Required by default by JPA, public or protected constructor, with no arguments.
    protected Usuario()
    {
        this.filhosComoPai = new HashSet<>();
        this.filhosComoMae = new HashSet<>();
    }

    /** For anyone who works with this class, it must provide a CPF, guaranteeing uniqueness, thus preventing this class from suffering problems when it is inside collections. */
    public Usuario(String cpf)
    {
        if(Util_Validador.isCPFValido(cpf) == false)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("CPF não encontra-se válido.");
        }

        this.cpf = cpf;

        this.filhosComoPai = new HashSet<>();
        this.filhosComoMae = new HashSet<>();
    }

    // Name
    public void setNome(String nome)
    {
        if(Util_Validador.isNomeValido(nome, 8) == false)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Nome de pessoa não encontra-se válido.");
        }

        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login)
    {
        if(Util_Validador.isLoginValido(login, 8) == false)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Login não encontra-se válido.");
        }

        this.login = login;
    }

    // Password
    public void setSenha(byte[] senha)
    {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    // Birthday
    public void setNascimento(LocalDate nascimento)
    {
        this.nascimento = Date.valueOf(nascimento);
    }

    // Gender
    public void setGenero(Genero genero)
    {
        if(genero == null)
        {
            throw new NullPointerException("O gênero passado como argumento encontra-se nulo.");
        }

        this.genero = genero.getID();
    }

    /** Defines a father for this person (child).*/
    public void setPai(Usuario pai)
    {
        // It is already?
        if( this.pai == null ||
            this.pai.equals(pai) == false)
        {
            // Remove previous father from this child.
            if(this.pai != null)
            {
                this.pai.removeFilho(this);
            }

            // Defines the new father for this child.
            // There may be a null assignment here!
            this.pai = pai;

            // Add this child to a new parent.
            if(pai != null)
            {
                if(pai.getFilhos().contains(this) == false)
                {
                    pai.addFilho(this);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Same logic.
    public void setMae(Usuario mae)
    {
        if( this.mae == null ||
            this.mae.equals(mae) == false)
        {
            if(this.mae != null)
            {
                this.mae.removeFilho(this);
            }

            this.mae = mae;

            if(mae != null)
            {
                if(mae.getFilhos().contains(this) == false)
                {
                    mae.addFilho(this);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Long getID()
    {
        return this.id;
    }

    // Name
    public String getNome()
    {
        return this.nome;
    }

    public String getLogin()
    {
        return this.login;
    }

    // Password
    public byte[] getSenha()
    {
        return this.senha;
    }

    // CPF = Brazil's Social ID
    public String getCPF()
    {
        return this.cpf;
    }

    // Birthday
    public LocalDate getNascimento()
    {
        return this.nascimento.toLocalDate();
    }

    // Gender
    public Genero getGenero()
    {
        return Genero.getGenero(
                Long.getLong(
                        Byte.toString(this.genero)));
    }

    // Father
    public Usuario getPai()
    {
        return this.pai;
    }

    // Mother
    public Usuario getMae()
    {
        return this.mae;
    }

    // Date and time of registration (produced by database after insertion).
    public LocalDateTime getCadastro()
    {
        return this.cadastro.toLocalDateTime();
    }

    // Children of this person
    public Set<Usuario> getFilhos()
    {
        // "Genero" is a enum type (Gender), with MALE ("HOMEM") and FEMALE ("MULHER").
        if(this.getGenero() == Genero.HOMEM)
        {
            return Collections.unmodifiableSet(this.filhosComoPai);
        }

        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(this.filhosComoMae);
    }

    // Add a child ("filho") to this person.
    public boolean addFilho(Usuario filho)
    {
        this.isUsuarioNula(filho);
        boolean add = false;

        // FATHER
        if(this.getGenero() == Genero.HOMEM)
        {
            add = this.filhosComoPai.add(filho);

            if(add)
            {
                if( filho.getPai() == null || 
                    filho.getPai().equals(this) == false)
                {
                    Usuario paiAnterior = filho.getPai();

                    if(paiAnterior != null)
                    {
                        paiAnterior.removeFilho(filho);
                    }

                    filho.setPai(this);
                }
            }
        }
        // MOTHER
        else
        {
            add = this.filhosComoMae.add(filho);

            if(add)
            {
                if( filho.getMae() == null ||
                    filho.getMae().equals(this) == false)
                {
                    Usuario maeAnterior = filho.getMae();

                    if(maeAnterior != null)
                    {
                        maeAnterior.removeFilho(filho);
                    }

                    filho.setMae(this);
                }
            }
        }

        return add;
    }

    // Removes the child ("filho") from this person.
    public boolean removeFilho(Usuario filho)
    {
        this.isUsuarioNula(filho);
        boolean rem = false;

        // FATHER
        if(this.getGenero() == Genero.HOMEM)
        {
            rem = this.filhosComoPai.remove(filho);

            if(rem)
            {
                if( filho.getPai() == null ||
                    filho.getPai().equals(this) == false)
                {
                    filho.setPai(null);
                }
            }
        }
        // MOTHER
        else
        {
            rem = this.filhosComoMae.remove(filho);

            if(rem)
            {
                if( filho.getMae() == null ||
                    filho.getMae().equals(this) == false)
                {
                    filho.setMae(null);
                }
            }
        }

        return rem;
    }

    // Just to print the same message.
    private void isUsuarioNula(Usuario p)
    {
        if(p == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Usuario passada em argumento encontra-se nula.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if (o == null) 
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (o == this) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (o.getClass() != this.getClass()) 
        {
            return false;
        }

        Usuario c = (Usuario) o;

        // This ensures consistent data work, and prevents something from happening silently, without us knowing why it happened.
        if(c.getCPF() == null || c.getCPF().length() <= 0)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Valor de CPF inexistente. Uma comparação não é possível.");
        }

        return c.getCPF().equals(this.getCPF());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        // I'm using Apacho Commons Lang.
        return new HashCodeBuilder()
                .append(this.getCPF()).toHashCode();
    }
}
```

The database is already created. I'm testing this on my personal pc.

### EDIT 2

I would like to share my project. Unfortunately I do not know how to use Github, and my post have almost 30k characters, so I uploaded my project (made with Eclipse Mars 2) as a war file. Here are the links:

http://www.megafileupload.com/8hon/Sistema_Teste_001.war (click on free user download to download the war file)

[mirror](http://www.filedropper.com/sistemateste001) (click on download this file to download)

To help, each package contains a file named "package-info". If in case you have any questions, check out this file. Other than that, english comments have been added for clarification.

I'm so sorry. I know it's not very convenient to download my project this way, but it was the only solution I found at the time. That way you can fully see my project.

And answering your question, I'm testing this code in the normal way, as an executable Java program. The Q classes are being generated, and my IDE is not accusing any syntax errors or anything. I'm right clicking my project and choosing "Run As..." -> "3 Java Application" to run. To generate my Q classes I'm clicking on "Run As..." -> "8 Maven generate-sources".

Comment: I think you are having some problems with your naming of classes and class location.  Do you have an Entity named Usuario with an @Entity annotation?

Comment: @M.Rizzo Hi! Thank you for your comment. So, I updated my question. Can you take a look, please? What do you think?

Comment: That does look good.  Have you checked the output directory <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory> and are the queryDSL Q classes being produced and resident in the folder.  Also any information on how your running your test will be helpful.  Are you running the tests as just part of your maven buid?

Comment: @M.Rizzo Thank you again for your time and attention. I made a edit (edit 2). Can you take a look, please? What do you think now? You have been very courteous. Thank you, really!

Comment: I can not do anything with those downloads as there being detected as potentially malicious.  If you can get into Github I will take a look.  Thanks for the additional details.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well I'm embarrassed to say  I didn't catch this sooner.  Your syntax on your query is actually wrong

```
return new JPAQueryFactory(this._em)
        .select(QUsuario.usuario)
        .where(QUsuario.usuario.id.eq(id))
        .fetchOne();
```

should be

```
 return new JPAQueryFactory(this._em)
        .selectFrom(QUsuario.usuario)
        .where(QUsuario.usuario.id.eq(id))
        .fetchOne();
```

Its **selectFrom** instead of select.

Comment: Well, the version of Querydsl that I'm using (4.1.4) does not have the method `selectFrom`. Instead, it has two methods: `select`, and `from`. After putting both together... EVERYTHING IS WORKING LIKE A GLOVE!!! THANK YOU! I'll never forget your help! And I'm sorry. You were not the only one who did not see it. We're in the same boat. Thanks for your attention and patience these days, really. Cheers! :]

Comment: `JPAQuery` doesn't have `selectFrom` but `JPAQueryFactory` does. I believe the exception message, while correct, is not very helpful. If they added something like "did you use from?" that would also suggest solution to a problem it would be nice indeed.

Comment: Ran into this as well. Apparenty you have to use select(field).from(entity) like this:  return new ArrayList<>(new JPAQueryFactory(getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession())
        .select(qMyEntity.idInternal).from(qMyEntity)
        .where(qMyEntity.status.eq(WAITING)
            .and(qMyEntity.deleteDateInternal.isNull()))
        .fetch());

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that the generated sources are not on the build path within your Eclipse project.  Therefore when you run your Java application it is not able to find the Q source files/classes. Right click on your Eclipse Mars project and select the "Properties" option.  Make sure you are on the "Source" tab and click "Add Folder" and select the target/generated-sources/java folder and Click "OK".  This will add the generated-sources to your Eclipse Mars project.  Then try running your Java main class.

Comment: Since yesterday I was trying to use github and got no luck. I guess you can see everything now. It's all here: https://github.com/loagit/sistema_teste_001/tree/teste And I did what you said. Got no luck also. I'm sorry. But please, take a look at my git repo. Thank you again!

Comment: So far I had not tested a connection to the database without using Querydsl. I tried doing this normally with pure JPA, with EntityManager. I discovered a new error. It was missing to include the following in my Spring settings (spring-config.xml): `<tx: annotation-driven transaction-manager = "transactionManager" />` I was able to connect and insert a new record without using Querydsl. I thought this would solve my situation, however, when trying to use Querydsl again I came across the same problem. I've been trying to sort this out for days... This is killing me...